# Inequality involving moments of a distribution

Tags: inequality, expected-value, cauchy-schwarz-inequality, integral-inequality

Let X be a real random variable. Under what conditions on the distribution do we have that

$$\mathbb{E}( X^{2n + 2}) \geq \mathbb{E}( X^{2n}) \mathbb{E}( X^{2})$$

for all integer $n$?

I tried using the Cauchy Shwartz inequality but it seems I would need to have the expectation values squared. Is there some general inequality you would recommend I start from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have, for all positive integer $n$,
$$\mathbb{E}(X^{2n + 2})
- \mathbb{E}(X^{2n}) \mathbb{E}(X^{2})
= \frac{1}{2}\mathbb{E}[(X^{2n} - Y^{2n})(X^2 - Y^2)]
\ge 0$$
where $Y$ is independent of $X$ and $Y \sim X$, and we have used
$$(a^n - b^n)(a - b)
= (a - b)^2(a^{n-1} + a^{n-2}b + \cdots + a b^{n - 2} + b^{n-1}) \ge 0$$
for all $a, b \ge 0$.

Answer (score 0):

It is always true for **non-negative** integers $n$. $EX^{2}\leq (EX^{2n+2})^{2/(2n+2)}$ and $EX^{2n}\leq (EX^{2n+2})^{2n/(2n+2)}$ by Hoder's inequality. Multiply these two to get $EX^{2}EX^{2n} \leq EX^{2n+2}$.